# Expression for Gibb's free energy change for a cell reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, free-energy

According to [Chemistry Libretexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_Principles_of_Modern_Chemistry_(Oxtoby_et_al.)/UNIT_4%3A_EQUILIBRIUM_IN_CHEMICAL_REACTIONS/17%3A_Electrochemistry/17.2%3A_The_Gibbs_Free_Energy_and_Cell_Voltage), the Gibbs free energy change of a cell reaction is related to the cell voltage as

$$ \Delta G = -nFE,$$

where $n$ is the number of moles of electrons passed and $F$ is the charge on a mole of electrons.

But $E$ decreases in value through the course of the cell reaction, so  shouldn't
$$\Delta G = -\int_{q_\mathrm{i}}^{q_\mathrm{f}} E\,\mathrm dq,$$

where $q_\mathrm{f} - q_\mathrm{i} = nF?$

Comment: It's strange to see a question like that from Michael Faraday.

Answer (score 3):

According to **Nernst's equation**,

$$E = E^o - \frac{RT}{nF}\ln Q$$

As you can see, $E$ is **independent** of $q$, therefore your proposed integral becomes,

$$\Delta G = - \int_{q_i}^{q_f}{E\cdot dq} = -E\int_{q_i}^{q_f}{dq} = -E\Delta q = -nFE$$

---

**Alternatively**, you can prove the the relation between Gibbs energy and cell potential as,

- Multiply Nernst's equation by $nF$, we get,

$$nFE = nFE^o - RT\ln Q$$

- Swapping the sides, we get,

$$-nFE = -nFE^o + RT\ln Q$$

- As we know,

$$\Delta G = \Delta G^o + RT\ln Q$$

$$\Rightarrow \Delta G = -nFE$$

Comment: so you are saying  that the concentration "Q" is completely unrelated to the charge?

Comment: But 'q' is the amount of charged passed from the cathode to the anode of the electrolytic cell. And for charge to pass, a species must be reduced at the cathode and a species must be oxidized at the anode. The concentration of the species in the chemical equation changes, and hence Q is related with 'q'.. And if Q is related with q, then E is also related with q (from Nernst equation)..

Correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: Any chemical reaction follows some "nth order kinetics", so the conc comes out to be a function of time, therefore Q should also be a function of time. Now, the integral is with respect to charge passed, hence E comes out.

Comment: @Rahul Verma if Q is a function of time, then by nernst equation, E is a function of time. Since it requires finite time to pass charge, E would vary as the charge is being passed. So E cannot be taken out of the integral since it's not constant.

Comment: @MichaelFaraday: as you know, ∆G is a state fn, so I think the integral isn't required. It is because ∆H, ∆S and T are state / point fn